# Configuration Cosmos DB, Bulk Insert Library in Data Factory v2

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

According to the documentation, the data factory v2 connector for cosmos db uses the [bulk executor library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-bulkexecutor-dotnet-getting-started).

Data Factory's copy activity has the parameters "Data integration unit", "Degree of copy parallelism" and "write batch size".

I'm experimenting with finding optimal settings, as I'm sure it *depends* on data size, rows, etc etc, but I want to understand what they mean in this context.

When set to auto; "Data integration unit" and "Degree of copy parallelism" seem to be set to 4. Of course I'm sure this depends of provisioned RU/s etc etc... I also read that relational like linked services ignore parallelism anyway, but I'm not sure if CosmosDB fits into that bracket.

**Degree of copy parallelism**

When reading through the performance recommendations, it suggests that a single BulkExecutor is spawned per application, which is contrary to my understanding of "Degree of copy parallelism".

I thought that "Degree of copy parallelism" is the number of threads i.e. would be the number of BulkExecutor's spawned. Whereas the recommendations sound as though BulkExecutor  will managed it's own threads. Unless this is in fact the "maxConcurrencyPerPartitionKeyRange" parameter?

Write batch size does appear to be used, when monitoring the batches I see the entire dataset read from source, and the batches being written to the destination. However it looks as though BulkExecutor handles batching optimally internally, should the batch size instead be 0 or perhaps very big instead? Or could that lead to memory problems on the integration units (azure or self hosted)?

Also, I presume the bulk executor when data factory is set to empty for write batch timeout will retry indefinitely during congestion or will it die at some point?